# Google Chrome Image Ceiling?

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome

We’re using Chrome for an interactive installation and appear to have hit some sort of image loading ceiling.

The app is built for a multitouch device and runs at 1920x1080. It's built on backbone and involves the rendering and removing of a large number of views which contain sprite animations (facilitated by the stepping of transparent png background images).

We’re preloading all of the images and listening for completion using David Desandro’s imagesloaded plugin. This worked perfectly at first (with less assets) and appears to work now, until you navigate further into the application. Despite the absence of 404s in the console and the confirmed presence of the files some of the images aren’t loaded and simply don’t appear. The problem persists even if we don’t preload the images.

The typical size of an animation sequence is 92250px x 450px and they come in any where between 1mb and 10mb each (that's after they've been optimised using the compressors behind grunt-contrib-imagemin). The image assets total is around 300mb.

What we’ve tried:

1. Applying any cache related flags in the chrome command line arguments when launching chrome (http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) such as `--disk-cache-size`.
2. Caching all of the media assets using the HTML5 cache manifest.
3. Testing on different machines, both mac and PC. This produces the same results.

What we’re currently trying:

1. Reducing the size of all of the images by removing every other frame in the animations. This isn't ideal.
2. Changing the animation method to switch out (preloaded) individual images rather than sprites.
3. Preloading images in batches just before they're about to be added (not ideal).

Ideally we'd like to remove the ceiling on whatever this limit we've hit is. Any help/insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it still hit problems if you just use the same image file multiple times (trying to identify if it could be the size of the assets themselves, or the process involved in rendering an asset)?

Comment: @dtt101 just tested this: there are no issues with one image being loaded multiple times. It appears to be some sort of memory/render tree limit...

Comment: I found this "chrome://net-internals/#httpCache" which might help to debug - though I am sure you are already aware!

Comment: Did you try the same thing on Firefox. I bet it works. I have a similar issue. I pipe a bunch of images to the client. And Chrome skips some of them.

Comment: @EvrenBingøl it doesn't run properly on Chrome due to other dependencies. We've narrowed down the issue to large sprite sheets which we were using for animations. Swapping these out fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst we haven't really got to the bottom of what is causing this issue, we have implemented a work around. Switching out the large sprite sheet animations for individual PNG frames does the job. I'd still be interested to learn exactly what the issue/limitation was for future reference...